# Incorrect Rotation for Imported Vertical Video in *Movie Clip Editor*

Tags: video, motion-capture, movie-clip-editor

Unexpectedly, blender rotates the vertical video shot on my iPhone when I import it into the Movie Clip Editor. How can I rotate the footage in the *Movie Clip Editor* view so I can clearly work with the tracking options without the footage being rotated the whole time during the editing process?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can open your movie in video editing and then insert the rotation value 90/-90 as you need it and then just render it out and use the result for your tracking.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that certainly works, although I hope in the future blender support other aspect ratios correctly! It seems a bit odd that I have to render an entirely. new video with black bars on the side of it to get this working!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Worked like a charm. But why in the first place does Blender import my video as rotated by 90? The video is shot on iPhone and has the dimensions of 1080x1920 (HDR, 60fps, .mov) but Blender imports it as 1920x1080...

Answer (score 0):

Open windows films and tv --> pencil icon --> trim --> trim off a single frame off the end or beginning of your video.
[image: trim]
when you open the trimmed version, it should be the right orientation
[image: portrait orientation appears correctly]

Comment: Your answer uses unnamed program for trimming the video and does not explain how trimming the last video frame will get rid of the rotation metadata in the video file.

Comment: @RumenBelev It's not an "unnamed program", the name is "Films & TV" (I admit it the notation is incorrect in the answer, but Google search will nevertheless find it that way) and it is installed with Windows 10. In the US it is called "Movies & TV" other than the rest of the world, as far as I know. But how this changes the rotation... maybe the one answering here does not even know. My simple guess is: since "Films & TV" seems to be able to play it correctly and trimming it forces to save it new replacing the old file, maybe the new file has rotation informations Blender understands.